# NSScrollView + layer-backing

Tags: layer, nsscrollview

I have this hierarchy:

NSPageController -> NSScrollView -> NSView 1 (same size as scroll view) -> centered NSView 2 (a page in a catalog) -> more subviews (interactive elements on page)

this is from the NSPageController sample, I replaced the NSImageView there with NSView 1.

Now I want to enable layer-backing and set the wantsLayer and layer redraw policy.

The problem I'm having is that as soon as I turn layer backing on the NSScrollView it no longer properly updates the layer bounds of NSView 1 when zooming the scroll view with a pinch gesture on a trackpad.

What am I missing to have the trickle down of layer-backing work?

Also, I found that if I enable layer-backing beginning with NSView 2, then the resizing works, but the page image I'm drawing there looks very coarse. I moved to NSView 1 with the layer-backing because I also want a shadow on NSView 2 and this only shows up if the superview has layer-backing turned on as well.